# GenABEL: Missing sex "NA" in plant GWAS

Tags: r, bioinformatics, genetics

I want to use GenABEL for GWAS in a diploid plant species, but GenABEL stuck on as it requires a "sex" column in pheno file. It should be filled with "1" for male or "0" for female. But I am working with a plant species. What should I do?

Error in R:

```
impute <- load.gwaa.data(phe="traits.dat", gen="gen0tped.raw", force=TRUE)
```

> Error in if (length(a) == 1 && !(names(a)[1] == 0 || names(a)[1] == 1)) stop("the column named \"sex\" contains 1 code which is neither 0 (=female) or 1 (=male)") : 
>     missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the details section of `?load.gwaa.data`:

> The first column of the phenotype file MUST contain the subjects'
>   unique ID, named "id"; there should also be a column named "sex" and
>   giving sex information (0 = female, 1 = male). Other columns in the
>   file should contain phenotypic information. Missing values should be
>   coded with "NA"

So try including a `sex` column with every value as `NA`.

Also, contact the maintainer (`packageDescription("GenABEL", fields = c("Maintainer", "BugReports"))`) to explain that GWASs can be done on things where gender isn't relevant.

Comment: Thanks for a nice reply....I've checked group queries and found a solution. I am working on it and trying to do an association analysis using genabel its taking time as m not handy on r.